# Way to manually enable Screensaver/Clock Screen?

Tags: gnome, lock-screen, notification, screensaver

Here's a problem I have: I step away from my laptop, a notification/message arrives (e.g., an email), Gnome Screensaver activates (i.e., the clock screen), I return to my computer and swipe the touchpad to show the screensaver/clock screen in order to see if any notifications are present but none are displayed on the screensaver/clock screen because the email message arrived before the screensaver activated.

This problem could be solved if I could engage the screensaver/clock screen before stepping away from my computer. I can do this if I lock the screen, but I don't wan't to lock the screen and force me to have to enter a password on return.

Is there any way to manually engage the screensaver/clock screen (preferably by keyboard shortcut) without locking the screen?

Comment: Using Gnome. I can enable the lock screen with CTRL+L. I would like to also have the option of enabling the screensaver/clock screen without locking. Perhaps not possible. I'm trying to solve the problem I presented; maybe there is a different solution.

Comment: @PRATAP? Far as I know there is version GNOME. How do you describe the version that is nothing else but just GNOME?

Answer (score 2):

***OS - Ubuntu 19.10***

Run the below command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
```

Create a shortcut with below command

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.ScreenSaver --object-path /org/gnome/ScreenSaver --method org.gnome.ScreenSaver.SetActive true
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: I already have that gsetting set to false. Thank you for your answer, but does your method enable me to cause the screensaver to activate at a time of my choosing? My read of it seems to just control whether lock is enabled or not and not when the screensaver activates.

Comment: @G.W Can you check the .gif added in the Answer..